# CSS Slideshow not showing image until clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

So I've been trying to implement the slideshow that is on the W3Schools website for a while now.
(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

I've gotten it to work but the first image is not loading. Only when I click on the left/right buttons or the radio buttons does the image show.

I'll attach a screen shot of what I mean.
[image: before clicking the buttons]
[image: after clicking]

I thought this might be an issue with having the display:none; but surely changing this means that you get all of the images loading at the same time.

EDIT: Code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.dealshead section {
  padding-left: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -45px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img class="mySlides fade" src="images\whiteonblack.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides fade" src="images\blackonwhite.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides fade" src="images\yellowonred.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Yeah, sorry there you go @jas7457

Comment: The code is working properly. the issue you might be having is that you are running the script before the html. try shifting the js code after the HTML

Comment: @SatpalTanan I'm linking the script to my html code like this: <script src="carousel.js"></script> at the top of my HTML code

Comment: Add this script after section tag, like in my example replace the whole script with  <script src="carousel.js"></script>

Comment: @SatpalTanan Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited the code, can you try now, i had changed the image path please revert to your image paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159299/discussion-between-satpal-tanan-and-daniel-lawton).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have gone through your code and link provided by you.
Your HTML part loads after the javascript part.
The second line of your javascript code i.e,
`showSlides(slideIndex);`
sets the display property of `slideIndex` (i.e,1) to block
later the HTML part loads and it has the value `mySlides` for attribute `class` which sets the `display` property to `none`.
After that the javascript part runs smootly.
So, there are two solutions:

1. Place the  tag just before the body tag ends.or,
2. Invoke `showSlides(slideIndex)` after the loading of HTML part by keeping the following code just before the end of body tag:

   `<script>
     showSlides(slideIndex);
   </script>`

Comment: YOU'RE A LIFE SAVER.

Comment: can anyone elobrate on this above solution, even im facing same problrm. @Anuj Sharma

Comment: Can you please explain it further? I have also same problem. I am using it with Django. I did not get your explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
I have one sample code ( bootstrap slider )`

 - **enter code here**

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" styleenter code here="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate this but I'm trying to use CSS or CSS+JS to create this slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected, Putting in a html file this works as expected

```
<style>
.dealshead section {
    padding-left: 200px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -45px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
</style>


<section>
<img class="mySlides fade" src="images\whiteonblack.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides fade" src="images\blackonwhite.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides fade" src="images\yellowonred.jpg" style="width:100%">
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
</section>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```