# Slider in HTML. Picture is disappearing after some seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to put slider in my ecommerce django website. But, while doing this I am getting an error. I don't what's the problem. I got this code from w3school. There it worked well, but in my code it's not working properly.
**html**

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <img src="{% static 'images/ad1.png' %}" style="width:100%">

</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <img src="{% static 'images/ad1.png' %}" style="width:100%">
 
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <img src="{% static 'images/ad1.png' %}" style="width:100%">
  
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" style="margin-left:-5%;"> <img src="{% static 'images/arrow-left-1.png' %}"></a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"style="margin-right:-5%;"> <img src="{% static 'images/arrow-right-2.png' %}"></a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

***style***

```
 * {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle; }

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
/*.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

***script***

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

It's working well, but disappearing after about a second and when to press next showing the picture, but again disappearing. Please, help!

Comment: Are you using some sort of rendering tool? I think you should mention what you are using for back end for this.

Comment: I am using Django

Comment: In this post it was somehow explained. But, I could not get it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368940/css-slideshow-not-showing-image-until-clicked

Comment: If it is a slideshow then you could use bootstrap. That would make things more easy. And check for the image loading.